# Library for introspection in Java

Tags: java, spring

Is there a class for introspection in Java that can get the fields, methods and annotations of an class, including those from **superclasses**, and **caches** the result?

**Edit**
Every major framework like spring, hibernate, jackson does some kind of deep introspection and I am interested to know if there is something in these libraries I can use.

Comment: I don't understand, what else do you need not provided by java reflection?

Comment: I have written the code a few times, just want to see if there a wheel already made.

Comment: Reflection *is* the wheel. You don't really need to do any additional "caching" (unless catching all the `NoSuchMethodException`s and whatnot is getting too annoying).

Comment: @ruakh Java String class a provides functions to work with strings, but there is apache StringUtils that most people tend to use.  I am looking for something in the similar vine.

Comment: @ruakh Unless I am much mistaken, reflection can only you get the fields, methods and annotations of the class, but not its superclasses.  And reflection does have noticeable performance impact, hence caching.

Comment: @Itfishie: You can certainly get the superclasses via reflection; that's what `java.lang.Class.getSuperclass()` is for. And while reflection is slower than calling methods directly, but caching obviously won't help with that; and I don't think caching will help all that much when it comes to looking up the methods and fields to begin with. Apache BeanUtils, for example, always re-performs all reflection before calling a method reflectively, rather than remembering information it had previously obtained.

Comment: It would help if you said what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I found what I am looking for in Spring BeanWrapper:

```
final BeanWrapper sourceBean = new BeanWrapperImpl(MyType.class);
final PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = sourceBean.getPropertyDescriptors();
for (final PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
   logger.info(propertyDescriptor.getName() + ":" + propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType());
}
```

With BeanWrapper you have access to all fields, setter and getter, annotations.  Each class is also cached.

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). It provides a nice set of helpers that make instrospection (mainly on Java bean properties) a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Spring framework's BeanWrapper has improved a lot after version 3, that's a fact. But if you want a more performant BeanWrapper you might want to consider juffrou-reflect's BeanWrapper - it is more performant in instantiating and even more performant in setting and getting values and types. And it's also more flexible than Spring's.

I'm biased, of course, because I developed Juffrou-reflect myself, but I do think you can get more out of my BeanWrapper. I started developing it when spring's BeanWrapper was in version 2.x and I didn't let got ever since. It's also open source so you are completely free to use and modify.

This is an example use case:

```
BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapper(BeanWrapperContext.create(Programmer.class)); // Programmer extends Person
beanWrapper.setValue("specialization", "Bean Wrappers :)"); // set value to Programmer's property
beanWrapper.setValue("firstName", "Carlos"); // set value to Person's property
beanWrapper.setValue("home.town", "Lisboa");        // set value to a nested bean's property
for(String propertyName : beanWrapper.getPropertyNames()) {
    Type type = beanWrapper.getType(propertyName);
    Object value = beanWrapper.getValue(propertyName);
    Logger.debug(type + ": " + value);
}
Programmer programmer = (Programmer) beanWrapper.getBean();  // get the wrapped object
BeanWrapperContext context = beanWrapper.getContext(); // Reuse the context and save on introspection overhead
```

You can check it out at http://juffrou.sourceforge.net. There is also a comprehensive PDF manual and javadocs so you can tap its full potential right from the start. But if you have any questions regarding it's use, i'll be more than happy to respond.

Cheers

Carlos

Comment: Hi! Quick question. Can your framework be used in a multi threaded scenario? Is there any documentation available as to which classes and method are thread safe/not safe? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for asking. I have not created any specific tests to probe concurrence in multi-threaded scenarios, but I am confident that it is ok to multi-thread with juffrou-reflect. All BeanWrappers are individual isolated instances. Only the context with static metadata is shared, so I think it is safe. In the mean time I moved the project to Github (http://cemartins.github.io/juffrou), and I am actively continuing its development there. Any feedback would be great.